# How to find a nested element in a dynamically generated scala-template list with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scala

I have some sort of board on which you can ask questions and write answers to them.

This is what it looks like:
[image: Example]

First comes the questions, then the answer(s). You can up-/downvote every Q/A, so they all have a score.

With a jQuery script you can change the value of the score of the questions, but it's not working right.
When I hit `upvote` on a question, all(!) scores for the example in the picture become "76454" ... basically (all scores of the Q/As concatenated) + 1.

The up-/downvoting on an answer works fine.
I think there might be a problem with the `span class="num"` for the votescore, but I dont know how I can select the nested answers and NOT the questions and vice versa. How can this be done?

My view class:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Frage- / Antwort-Teil</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="list-group">

    @for(question <- questionList){

    <!-- Questions -->
    <li class="list-group-item" >
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"  id="upvoteButton" 
            value="voteUp" style="width: 30px; height: 30px; text-align: center; vertical-align: center;">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>

        <span class="num" id="@question.questionID">@question.voteScore</span>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="downvoteButton" 
            value="voteDown" style="width: 30px; height: 30px; text-align: center;">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
        (...)

    <!-- Answers -->
    <ul class="list-group" style="margin-left:20px" >
        @for(answer <- answerList){
            @if(question.questionID == answer.questionID){

            <li class="list-group-item" > 
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default answerTest" id="upvoteButton" 
                    value="voteUp" style="width: 30px; height: 30px; text-align: center;">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>

                <span class="num" id="@question.questionID">@answer.voteScore</span>
                (...)
```

My jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn-default").click(function(){
        if( $(this).val() == 'voteUp'){

            $(this).html( "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up' aria-hidden='true' style='color:orange'></span>" );

            var currentScore = $(this).parent('li').find('.num').text();
            $(this).parent('li').find('.num').html(parseInt(currentScore) + 1);

            var currentID = $(this).parent('li').find('.num').attr('id');
            (...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the immediate child `.num` of the `li`, not all the descendent `.num`s.  Use the child selector:

```
$(this).parent('li').find('> .num')
```